# Boost signals2 and shared pointer

Tags: c++, boost

I have 2 solutions. In first solution I have class

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::signal<void()>> wakeup_signal_ptr;
```

and also method get_wakeup_signal_ptr.

In the second solution I also have shared pointer with signal, I use method
method get_wakeup_signal_ptr from first solution to get pointer but when i want to connect this signal with lambda I have assertion: px != 0 in shared_ptr.

Any idea why ?
Best regards.

Small example of real code:

In first project I have:

```
class Implementation
{
    public:
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::signal<void()>> wakeup_signal_ptr;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::signal<void()>> get_wakeup_signal_ptr() {return(wakeup_signal_ptr);};
}
```

In second project I have:

```
   boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::signal<void()>> wakeup_signal_ptr;
   wakeup_signal_ptr = member_of_implementation->get_wakeup_signal_ptr();
   wakeup_signal_ptr->connect(boost::bind(&class_in_second_projet::method_for_invoke, this));
```

projects builds without any problems but in runtime I have

```
   Assertion failed: px != 0, file D:\project\3rdParty\Common\include\boost/s
   mart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp, line 648
```

when i reach code which is responsible for connect slot.

Comment: You have two solutions to *what*? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Please read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Oh, and you know that you should look at the smart pointers `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` more in terms of *ownership* than as regular pointers? If you have a resource that can have multiple simultaneous owners, use `shared_ptr`, and if the resource can only have a single owner at a time use `unique_ptr`. Using that semantic, I don't think it make much sense in having a shared pointer to a signal, at least not with the limited context we can see.

Comment: By Solution I mean Project (I work on Visual Studio and here we have solutions instead of projects). I try to figure out why I can't connect boost signal when signal is in shared pointer.

Joachim but if I use unique_ptr I will be able to 'Fire' signal in first project and handle it in second project (where signal is connect with lambda)

Comment: You may want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please update your question to include a problem description, not only what your solutions are. Also include things like errors or other problems you have with your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not saying this is a bad question or anything, I'm just trying to help you improve the question, and make it clearer, so you have better chances of getting good answers, and not having the question closed as to vague or broad.

Comment: Example added to first post

Comment: Just declaring a shared pointer doesn't actually allocate any memory for the pointed-to object. Have you allocated memory anywhere before calling `get_wakeup_signal_ptr()`? I.e. have you done something like `wakeup_signal_ptr = boost::make_shared<boost::signals2::signal<void()>>();`?

Comment: Thank you Joachim I completely forgot about allocating memory for pointer. I am not sure if i know how to mark your answer as solution for my problem.